# Event Registration Emails

Tags: civievent, joomla, email

I have set up an event and everything works fine, but no confirmation emails are being sent. we are only getting the emails from Paypal informing us of payment. I have tested the mail settings and left it at the default "mail" and the site is on a linux server. I do receive an email when I test the settings. I have made sure the email addresses entered are correct. I have added email addresses to make sure it's not just one server not receiving them.

The emails were working correctly for an event last year. Since then I have updated to 4.7.1.

Joomla 3.4.8

I don't know what else to do.

Thank you for any help. 
Patti

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pay later option their is no email sent in Civicrm 4.7.1 / 4.7.2
 Where as when payment is made using dummy payment processor an receipt is been sent out

I guess this is an Bug in this version so you could wait till the next release or you need to roll back to CiviCRM Version 4.6.10 where this option is working fine - Please raise an issue for the same so this gets fixed in next release

- I guess this helps

Comment: As far as I know I do not have the "pay later option" selected. All three tests have completed payment through Paypal, and they are listed as registered.

Comment: If you are using contribution page please select pay later option has a payment method then it should work